# Events on different experiments

Tags: probability-theory

I have two questions for Probability theory and hope getting your help.

**Question 1:** Consider the following two experiments:

$T_1$: "Tossing a fair coin".

$T_2$: "Tossing a fair six-sided die".

Let event $A$ be obtaining heads, and event $B$ be rolling a 6. Can we possibly use the addition rule 
$$P(A \cup B) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$
for the above events?

**Question 2:** We know that, if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events, then
$$P(A \cap B)=0.$$
Do both events $A$ and $B$ consider on a single performance of an experiment?

Comment: Q1: Yes, if you're looking for the probability of obtaining a heads or a 6. Q2: Not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean does the definition of mutually exclusive events necessarily consider on a single performance of an experiment?

Comment: The formula for the probability of a union gives no problem. Formally, we may consider the outcomes to be all ordered pairs $(X, k)$, where $X$ is one of $H$ or $T$, and $k$ is an integer from $1$ to $6$.

Comment: In practice you can always take the cartesian product of the two universes as a new universe. The only known cases which this is not possible is in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thank you all, André and kjetil. According to your arguments, I observe that if $P(A), P(B)>0$ in which $A$ and $B$ are events of separate experiments then $A$ and $B$ are never mutually exclusive. Because they are independent so $P(A \cap B) =P(A)P(B)>0$. Is that right?

Comment: Please see the earlier comment. Interpret events $A$ and $B$ as follows. Interpret $A$ as the set of all pairs $(H, k)$ where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $6$, and interpret $B$  as the set of all pairs $(X,6)$ where $X=H$ or $X=T$. Then $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive, indeed they are independent, and the product formula holds. (Note that the reinterpretation did not affect probabilities of $A$ or of $B$.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thank you for your helpful explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. I have been hoping someone will give a formal answer. The fact that one is in a product space is often not explained in elementary courses.